# Why isn't this pulling an array from another sheet?

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I am trying to pull a two dimensional array from another sheet and I keep getting an error on the following line:

```
FD_arr = FD.Range(Cells(2, 3), Cells(FD_TotalRows, 4)).Value
```

I can't figure out what is wrong with it.

```
Sub Combine()

    Dim FD_strArray As Variant
    Dim FD_TotalRows As Long

    Set FD = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FD")

    FD_TotalRows = FD.Rows(Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    FD_arr = FD.Range(Cells(2, 3), Cells(FD_TotalRows, 4)).Value
    MsgBox FD_arr(4, 1) & " " & FD_arr(4, 2)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to qualify the Cells calls with a worksheet as well.

```
FD_strArray = FD.Range(FD.Cells(2, 3), FD.Cells(FD_TotalRows, 4)).Value
```

Comment: @ExcelHero Not exactly unique to SO - people are weird. ;) I think it's more noticeable here because there are accepted answers and voting, but much the same behaviour occurs in all forums I frequent.